# My Scrapy is not Scraping anything (blank csv file)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap top 100 t20 batsmen from icc site however the csv file I'm getting is blank. There are no errors in my code (at least I don't know about them). 
Here is my item file

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    Ranking = scrapy.Field()
    Rating = scrapy.Field()
    Name = scrapy.Field()
    Nationality = scrapy.Field()
    Carer_Best_Rating = scrapy.Field()
```

dmoz_spider file

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "espn"
    allowed_domains = ["relianceiccrankings.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.relianceiccrankings.com/ranking/t20/batting/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        #sel = response.selector
        #for tr in sel.css("table.top100table>tbody>tr"):
        for tr in response.xpath('//table[@class="top100table"]/tr'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['Ranking'] = tr.xpath('//td[@class="top100id"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['Rating'] = tr.xpath('//td[@class="top100rating"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['Name'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="top100name"]/a/text()').extract_first()
            item['Nationality'] = tr.xpath('//td[@class="top100nation"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['Carer_Best_Rating'] = tr.xpath('//td[@class="top100cbr"]/text()').extract_first()
            yield item
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't know much about scrapy, but where do you request the html or write to a csv?

Comment: @cricket_007 in sel.css I pass the class name of the table,it's a for loop to fetch all the rows and each class in items is the class name mentioned in html related to the item list e.g 'Ranking' title has class = top100id. I hope this was what you were asking?

Comment: just saw your edited post. I wrote to the csv file by using the command "scrapy crawl espn -o items.csv"

Comment: Not really... I understand the XPath piece, but how do you get into that method?

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly are you asking, which method are you talking about? I just modified the dmoz tutorial of scrapy :/ I'm new to scrappy as well

Comment: The parse method. I looked at the tutorials, and I guess it's executed on its own. Anyways, are you sure you are selecting the correct elements or that the section of the webpage you want is not generated dynamically by Javascript (therefore not generated on the page load)?

Comment: Yes I'm have doubled check the elements I'm selecting. About the dynamically generated part I don't think it is generated dynamically the content is static

Comment: Personally, I would use beautifulsoup unless you specifically needed scrapy for something

Comment: I would shift to beautifulsoup but the time limit is quite short (and I have wasted a whole day in understanding scrapy ) :/ anyway thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you're trying to scrap had a frame in it which is the one you want to scrap.

```
start_urls = [
    "http://www.relianceiccrankings.com/ranking/t20/batting/"
]
```

This is the correct URL

Also there is a lot more stuff wrong going on,

- To select elements you should use the `response` itself, you don't need to initiate a variable with `response.selector` just select it straight from `response.xpath(//foo/bar)`
- Your css selector for the table is wrong. `top100table` is a class rather than an id therefore is should be `.top100table` and not `#top100table`.

Here just have the xpath for it:

```
response.xpath("//table[@class='top100table']/tr")
```

`tbody` isn't part of the html code, it only appears when you inspect with a modern browser.

- The `extract()` method **always** returns a list rather then the element itself so you need to extract the first element you find like this:

`item['Ranking'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="top100id"]/a/text()').extract_first()`

Hope this helps, have fun scraping!

Comment: Thank you so much for the correction :)  The csv file is generating but the problem is that it's extracting just the first element like for column "Ranking" it's just generating 1 for all batsmen same is the case is with "Rating" and "Career Best Rating", btw I have updated the code above :) Batsmen names are printing fine

Answer (score 0):

To answer your ranking problem, the xpath for Ranking starts with '//...' which means 'from the start of the page'. You need it to be relative to `tr` instead. Simply remove the '//' from every xpath in the for loop.

```
item['Ranking'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="top100id"]/text()').extract_first()
```